# How to know when an email is received

Tags: c#, email

I'm working on C# and I need to know when an email sent by my program is received at inbox folder of destinatary.
Is this possible?

Comment: In general it isn't unless you control the server on which the mailbox is.

Comment: Why dont you try services like mail gun which have API to send emails , you can use free or paid service depending on your email traffic. at least they have logs and return types (success/failures) so that you can check

Answer (score 0):

You Can try This Code

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 10000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Your Email Address", "Your Emaill Password");

            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("Sender Email", "Reciver Email", "subject", "body");
            mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

            client.Send(mm);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, we can't verify whether the mail has been reached to recipient's inbox. At max, we can verify that the mail sent is reached to recipient's email server. Once the email has left you, its no longer in your control. Consider, I send a mail from yahoo to Gmail. At max, I can verify that mail has been sent to gmail server but not user(s) inbox.

For SMS : Take twilio service for example, when you send a SMS to vodafone using twilio service, twilio will send SMS to vodafone(carriers) if carrier sends a response saying, message has been sent(Vodafone server) then only twilio can send back that status to you but sometimes even carrier will not send 'sent' status to twilio so its not guarantee.

So, in short you can't. No way you can confirm that mail has reached so and so person's inbox.